# Replace login shell with program (mini-jail)

Tags: shell, ssh, command-line, login

is there a better way, preferably without an extra software-stack, to lock specific ssh users into a program without access to a working shell? Imagine a cli program which should be the only interface a user has access to via ssh.

My hacky solution:

In */etc/passwd* replacing the user-shell with following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/bash -c /usr/bin/cli
exit 1
```

Comment: Any reason for not using /usr/bin/cli directly in /etc/passwd?

Comment: @YoMismo `Connection to 192.168.xx.xx closed.` Can't find any logs which shows why it fails...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue at Hand

You desire to lock remote users into using a specific shell when they connect to your server. As you have probably found out, `chsh` or other solutions are geared towards local users.

## Solution

As per [this solution by user muru](https://askubuntu.com/a/541586), I would edit your `sshd_config` to use the `ForceCommand` option.

> You could use a ForceCommand along with Match:
>
> ```
>  Match Address 10.1.0.0/16
>  ForceCommand /usr/bin/[some shell]
> ```
>
> From man sshd_config:
>
> ```
> Match   Introduces a conditional block.  ...
> ```
>
> > The arguments to Match are one or more criteria-pattern pairs or
> >              the single token All which matches all criteria.  The available
> >              criteria are User, Group, Host, LocalAddress, LocalPort, and
> >              Address.
>
> ```
> ForceCommand
> ```
>
> > Forces the execution of the command specified by ForceCommand,
> >              ignoring any command supplied by the client and ~/.ssh/rc if
> >              present.  The command is invoked by using the user's login shell
> >              with the -c option.
>
> So, the command you specify would be executed using the user's login shell, which must accept the -c option. The connection is closed when the command exits, so for all practical purposes, that command is their shell.

Using `ForceCommand` in your configuration file you can force the use of a shell that supports the `-c` option. I would also reference [this serverfault post](https://serverfault.com/questions/162018/force-ssh-to-use-a-specific-shell) to get more information on how to complete this task.

## Conclusion

Use your `sshd_config` options to force the use of a shell that can support `-c` as that will close the shell and session once complete.

Please comment if you have any questions or issues with this answer. I appreciate feedback to correct any misconceptions and to improve my posts. I can update my answer as needed.

Best of Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You would be better suited to create an actual BSD jail or chroot environment for the user in question. Of course that would require some manual creation of a user, group, mini linux file system, acquiring the libraries necessary for `cli` etc or using the `jail` tools available in unix distributions.

See the documents for more information

[Linux chroot](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-chroot-command-examples-usage-syntax/)

[BSD jail](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/jails.html)