how to ban a ssh user to run only a specific program
there is a a computer (homeserver) in the lan (24/4 on) with speakers connected.
the linux system can play music with the programm "mocp" (music on console).
i would like to give other users in the lan access to moc to play music.
they should connect with ssh to the computer.
but there must be a user they only can run the moc programm, if it ends, the ssh connection must end.
there is a specific directory (with the music to play) only this should moc and the ssh user see and use.
(if moc starts, it can be disconnected with "q" or with "Q" quit.)
is this possible, and how?

This may very well be a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/452213/116858
